# There is ClassnotFound Exception in my struts2 application

Tags: exception, struts2

```
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
filterclass>
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my `Filter` code. Is there anything wrong in it
I am getting severe `Exception` class not found error.

Comment: Are you deploying the complete set of required libraries (jars)? You should also supply the complete stack trace of the exception; we don't even know what class it says is missing, if there's a root cause, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your [`web.xml`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html). Also make sure `struts2-core-x.x.x.jar` is in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder as well as the complete set of required libraries. The core jar contains a class used by the filter configuration and loaded by server classloader when you deploy your application.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```